# Importing a local html file fails

Tags: import, windows, html

Anyone have any idea why this is failing?

The file is there. A file in the same (Windows 10) dir called "test.txt" imports exactly as expected. But .HTML files fail without a useful error message.

Thanks for the help.

```
In[25]:=  text = Import["C:\\Users\\johna\\Documents\\ChatsWithSimon\\messages.html"]

Out[25]= $Failed
```

---

[image: Trace@info image]

Comment: I assume `FileExistsQ` works and you have permission to read it(?) Try `Trace@Import[...]` and show the result in your question or on pastebin. Also will it import as text with `Import["...", "TEXT"]`? If that works it suggests an uncaught problem in parsing the html.

Comment: Import["...","Text"] worked like a charm.

Thank you.

Comment: ^ that's good to hear, but did you figure out why the HTML import failed? Did you manage to trace it? Such information could be useful for anyone else with this problem where they need to import HTML.

Comment: I traced it, but the results will not paste coherently here.

Comment: I added the trace result as an image in the original entry.

Comment: In the case  of a html file, you can also use "Source" instead of "TEXT". Or even "Hyperlinks" or "Images" or "ImageLinks" to extract specific parts of the file.